# Counting CASE in ORDER BY statement

Tags: sql

Unfortunately, my SQL is pretty rusty. I currently have a statement like this:

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM table_name WHERE
    field1 = 'A' OR field2 = 'B' OR field3 = 'C' ORDER BY
        CASE WHEN field1 = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN field2 = 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN field3 = 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    DESC LIMIT 1;
```

This query correctly finds the item with the most similarity to the "ideal" of `field1`, `field2`, `field3` being `A`, `B`, and `C` respectively. However, I'd also like to be able to find the count of the number of "matched" fields. It seems like I should be able to get it easily since I'm already performing that computation but I'm not sure how without another subquery.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED**

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3,
       CASE WHEN field1 = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
       CASE WHEN field2 = 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
       CASE WHEN field3 = 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END match_count
  FROM table_name 
 WHERE field1 = 'A' OR field2 = 'B' OR field3 = 'C' 
 ORDER BY match_count DESC
```

In this particular case (for **MySql**) you can substitute `CASE` with `(fieldX = 'N')`

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3,
       (field1 = 'A') + (field2 = 'B') + (field3 = 'C') match_count
  FROM table_name 
 WHERE field1 = 'A' OR field2 = 'B' OR field3 = 'C' 
 ORDER BY match_count DESC
```

Now to limit the resultset based on match_count use `HAVING` clause

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3,
       (field1 = 'A') + (field2 = 'B') + (field3 = 'C') match_count
  FROM table_name 
 WHERE field1 = 'A' OR field2 = 'B' OR field3 = 'C' 
HAVING match_count > 1
 ORDER BY match_count DESC
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/50c85/19)** demo for all above mentioned queries

Comment: I was looking for exactly that! Thanks for the code and demo.

Comment: SO wouldn't let me accept it without waiting a few minutes, sorry. Side question to my original one: is there an easy way to limit the query's results to those in which `match_count` > some threshold, without outputting `match_count` at all?

Comment: I suppose I can just do the `CASE` again and put it in an `AND` clause.

Comment: Nice; you're awesome. Neat little trick with summing the field booleans too, though it doesn't seem to work on my beloved Postgres. My question was actually about how to store match_count in this way and use it in `HAVING` and `ORDER BY` without having to display it as output. Not a big deal if I just do the summation once in a `HAVING` clause and once in an `ORDER BY` though.

Comment: @ConstableJoe Yes either repeat code in `HAVING` and `ORDER BY` or just wrap it up in outer `SELECT`